# Paper format of Springer LNCS

Tags: typography, print-design, paper-size

I found the paper format of Lecture Notes in Computer Science proceedings issued by Springer very nice. I tried to find out what is it, but I wasn't able to find it in [Wiki list of paper sizes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paper_size). The book size is `236mm x 155mm` (`9.3in x 6.1in`) after binding. I think it's `236mm x 157mm` (`9.3in x 6.2in`) before binding since that would make a `3:2` ratio.

I would like to know whether this paper size is recognized under any name/code.

(I basically ask because I wouldn't like to use a fairly non-standard paper size. However, part of me is quite curious about it as well.)

Comment: Is it softcover black and white, saddle stitch or perfect bound?

Comment: @Matt_2.0 Hi! It's soft-cover. I don't know what do you ask by "black and white", the cover is color, the book itself is BW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is what's known as a standard printing size.  However, some printers offer clients with alternative sizes that would increase the selection and demand.  Paper generally comes on a huge roll and is printed then trimmed to size:

[image]

The book you are curious about has a `6.69in x 9.61in` trim size on white Matte 66gsm/45lb. paper

Comment: Now tell me how do you know all the details about the paper! (Seriously, I wonder)

Comment: I have designed a few books to be printed before and this is one of the sizes.